# Can I use Keycloak as a key store like Hashicorp Vault for an example?

Tags: encryption, hash, hashicorp-vault

Can I use [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) as a key store like Hashicorp Vault for an example?
Keycloak has realm keys, can I use this feature as a secure key store and use it to encrypt and hash data in my web application? Is there an API that I can use to read those keys to use them in my web application? are these keys stored securely on disk?

If Keycloak is not built for that purpose, what should I use in combination with it? Can I integrate Keycloak with some other key vault?

Comment: When referencing a non-famous product, it is useful to link to it.

Comment: As this is a question about a specific product's capabilities, this is more of a question for them.

Comment: schroeder, I've checked the help center and found that my question is not off-topic. The question goes under "Security Tools" in "https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic". And the tools I am referencing are security tools. As "Security Tools" does not only reference tools used for Pen testing. I am sure there are a lot of professionals in this community who are willing to help in this question. Is there a specific reason why you put my question on hold?????

Comment: My specific reason is the one that I stated. These questions and use cases are better asked of the vendor. Some of your questions are found in the documentation (I checked).

Comment: Not all of them found in the documentation. And the reason I posted my question here is that the vendor takes a lot of time responding to inquiries. Anyway, I posted my question on other forums.